# Track how many times the Back button has been clicked via IIS Logs?

Tags: iis, back-button, logparser, iis-logs

Is it possible to track how many time the Back button on a web browser has been clicked on by parsing/ querying IIS Logs? I've seen a lot of solutions that uses Javascript, but I was just wondering if it's possible with IIS Logs.

Perhaps there's some sort of pattern I should be looking for in the cs(Referer) or cs-uri-stem?

Comment: That is a browser specific feature.